# Web Service returns Data and 401 unauthorized

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-3.5

I have a ASP.Net web service I am accessing via JQuery this works fine but I have noticed in Firebug that the request returns a **401 Unauthorized** Has anyone experienced this and more importnatly sorted it.

I am not sure what information to put here but if you need some info about my site to solve this please ask :)

Comment: Did you call web service from different web domain. (eg. myweb.com --> myservice.com)

Comment: no it is within the same domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to allow IIS anonymous access "read/execute" on web service directory. [HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication](http://goneale.com/2009/10/22/wcf-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-anonymous/)

Comment: This looks promising but i'm not sure how to chnage these settings for a debug version of the site. i guess I am going to have to bite the bullet and deploy to my dev server where I have more options.